# how to do a program that determines if a number is prime or composite

Tags: java

Im a beginner at using Java. For some reason, I cant get my program to properly determine if the number I type in is a prime or a composite number. Can someone show me what i'm doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean prime = true;

    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    int num1 = in .nextInt();
    int numval = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < num1; i = i + 1) {
        numval += 1;
        int test = num1;
    }
    if (num1 != 0) {
        System.out.println("This is a prime number");
        prime = false;

    }
    if (prime == true) {
        System.out.println("This is not a prime number");

    }
}
```

Comment: When you step through this code in your debugger, for a given input which produces incorrect output, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: `if(num1 != 0) { System.out.println("This is a prime number"); ... }` Surely, all numbers except 0 aren't prime numbers.

Comment: Your for-loop doesn't make sense, cause you're not doing anything that requires a loop - and you're not even using your two variables `numval` and `test` that are inside it.

Comment: Honestly, I started confusing myself around the end of my program. I kept changing my program time after time because it was never working. anyways, Thanks for the response. I need criticism if I want to get better at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the test variable but try something like this which is more cleaner.

```
boolean prime = true;
int num1 = in .nextInt();
// We know that composite numbers start from 2 and that 1 is neither prime nor composite.
if (num1 < 2) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number has to greater than 1");
}
for (int i = 2; i < num1; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (prime) {
    System.out.print("Number is a prime");
} else {
    System.out.print("Number is composite");
}
```

Comment: `i = 2` and `i < num1` together will give you problems if the input is less than `3`, no?

Comment: Thats true, I fixed it for numbers less than 2.

Comment: For 2 and 3, it won't go inside the for loop, so by default they are prime :)

Comment: You are correct about 2. I didn't realise that. However 3 will go into the loop, so that's not a problem. However, perhaps it is better to simply do `System.out.println("The number is neither prime nor composite.");` instead of throwing an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: We could but we also want the control flow to not go down any further if we can help it. In your suggestion, it will print "Neither prime nor composite" and execute the remainder of the logic unless we handle that case separately.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I really needed it. This is only like the 4th-5th program that I've done in my life, and only my first time doing loops.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you consider marking this as answered if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Prime number is that number whose has only two factors are 1 and itself. So you have to check that is it have any factor that is greater than 1 and less than N. For this reason you have to write a loop from **2 to N-1** to check whether it is possible to divide by any number from **2 to N-1**.

If it is possible to get any factor from the loop, then make variable `prime` as false and break from the loop because if we get one factor from the loop then it is not necessary to check the other factors.

And if we don't get any factor from the loop then the value of `prime` will be true as we initialized before.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean prime = true;

    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    int num1 = in .nextInt();

    if(num1<2)
    {
        System.out.println("Number should be greater than 1");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < num1; i = i + 1) {
        if (num1 % i == 0) {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (prime == true) {
        System.out.println("This is a prime number");

    }
    if (prime == false) {
        System.out.println("This is not a prime number");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  boolean prime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= num1; i = i + 1) {
      if (num1 % i == 0) {
        prime= false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (prime && num1>1) {
      System.out.println("This is a prime number");
    }else {
      System.out.println("This is not a prime number");
    }
```

Comment: adding a little explanation about the code snippet you provided would be more beneficial to OP

Comment: There's a number of improvements you could make to this. Firstly, if you have found that it's not a prime, then you can abort early, so you should put that in the final clause. Secondly, you only need to go up to srt(num) because once you go past there you don't need it. Lastly, you're testing all the even and odd numbers; you can test for %2 once, then start from %3 and go up by two each time.

Answer (score -1):

I know two ways:
Let's keep in mind 'number' is used.

1: ((number % 2) == 0)
2: ((number & 1) == 0)

I believe that'll return true for any prime and false otherwise.